# How to get OnClickListeners out of onCreate?

Tags: android

how can i get the OnClickListeners out of onCreate? I´m new to the Android programming and now I have it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pname = edtext.getText().toString();
            regstat = true;
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_studioreg);
        }
    });
}
```

But how can I get them in a new Method and what do I have to do to use them correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is 
in your onCreate

startbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
and then 
and then implement onclicklistener like below

```
 public calss Your_Class  implements OnClickListener {
```

and then

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub


   switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button 1 clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    case R.id.button2:

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button 2 clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     break;
    case R.id.button3:

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button 3 clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     break;
    case R.id.button4:

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button 4 clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;

   }
 }
```

you will set the id's of button in the xml like

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:text="Button 1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />
```

and same for other four buttons.

Comment: Sorry I´m a beginner: How does "public void onClick(View v) know which button I clicked ? when I got for example 4 Buttons ? Will you be so kind to show me how to do it with 2 or more buttons ?

Comment: @SimonFedermann okay now i know that problem see my updated answer.

Comment: @SimonFedermann if that answer helped you then kindly accept the answer and upvote it Tanks, have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ButterKnife API, your code will be cleaner like:

```
@OnClick(R.id.start_button)
public void onStartButtonTouched() {
   // TODO
}
```

http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/